# How to get Wordpress user's first name from WP_User object?

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a basic plugin. Here's my code:

```
    $new_user = get_userdata($user_id); //$user_id is passed as a parameter

$first_name1 = $new_user->user_firstname;
$last_name1 = $new_user->user_lastname;
    echo "<" . $first_name1 . $last_name1 . ">";
    //returns: <>

$first_name2 = $new_user-first_name;
$last_name2 = $new_user->last_name;
    echo "<" . $first_name2 . $last_name2 . ">";
    //returns: <>
```

According to [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata#Notes), this should work, but when I echo `$first_name` or `$last_name` they're empty. Strangely, *THIS* does work:

```
    $id = $new_user->ID;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE:

I `var_dump`ed  `$new_user` and those properties aren't in there! Is this because I'm calling it from inside a plugin in the /mu-plugins directory? Do those properties get added later?

```
object(WP_User)#334 (7) { ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#330 (10) { ["ID"]=> string(3) "758" ["user_login"]=> string(7) "emerson" ["user_pass"]=> string(34) "$P$BB2PuvRbyGUSVZR1M8FLSujPvMO2MW0" ["user_nicename"]=> string(7) "emerson" ["user_email"]=> string(16) "123esl@gmail.com" ["user_url"]=> string(0) "" ["user_registered"]=> string(19) "2012-08-17 01:03:27" ["user_activation_key"]=> string(0) "" ["user_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["display_name"]=> string(7) "emerson" } ["ID"]=> int(758) ["caps"]=> array(1) { ["subscriber"]=> string(1) "1" } ["cap_key"]=> string(15) "wp_capabilities" ["roles"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "subscriber" } ["allcaps"]=> array(15) { ["read"]=> bool(true) ["level_0"]=> bool(true) ["read_questions"]=> bool(true) ["read_answers"]=> bool(true) ["publish_questions"]=> bool(true) ["immediately_publish_questions"]=> bool(true) ["publish_answers"]=> bool(true) ["read_private_forums"]=> bool(true) ["publish_topics"]=> bool(true) ["edit_topics"]=> bool(true) ["publish_replies"]=> bool(true) ["edit_replies"]=> bool(true) ["assign_topic_tags"]=> bool(true) ["access_s2member_level0"]=> bool(true) ["subscriber"]=> string(1) "1" } ["filter"]=> NULL }
```

UPDATE2:

I tried this:

```
$user_meta = get_user_meta( $new_user->ID );
var_dump($user_meta);
```

and I got this (last_name and first_name are empty even though they're defined in the user's profile):

```
array(11) { ["wp_user_level"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["show_admin_bar_front"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "true" } ["wp_capabilities"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";s:1:"1";}" } ["use_ssl"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["admin_color"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "fresh" } ["comment_shortcuts"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "false" } ["rich_editing"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "true" } ["description"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["nickname"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "emerson" } ["last_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["first_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Comment: var_dump( $new_user ); You'll see exactly what is, and what is not available in that object.

Comment: Those properties are missing! I just updated the question with the var_dump. I'm confused why those properties aren't there.

Comment: You have to pass the ID to `get_user_meta` function.

Comment: Try `$new_user->first_name`. It won't show when you `var_dump` but it's there

Answer (score 37):

The user's first and last names are stored within the user_meta.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

So if you'd like to access all of that data, for example, try this:

```
$user_meta = get_user_meta( $new_user->ID );
```

Or, if you'd like to access a single meta value, try this:

```
$last_name = get_user_meta( $new_user->ID, 'last_name', true );
```

Comment: I tried that too and it didn't work. I `var_dump`ed `$last_name` after defining it with `get_user_meta()` and it was empty.

Comment: Have you actually set that information for $new_user? You see the structure of usermeta, though, right? The information should live there when it's set...

Comment: Yes. I updated the question to show how: `$new_user = get_userdata($user_id);` I know $new_user is defined because SOME of the properties are defined. That's the weird part. Why is $new_user->ID defined but not the others?

Comment: It looks like you haven't actually set those properties, thus they are blank.. Try editing your user information in the WP Admin panel, and I bet you they will show up. :) Or just modify/save the WP_User object with any meta you want it to have. $new_user->first_name = 'Emerson';

Comment: How can I manually set those properties if I can't return what they are?

Comment: Where is the user data generated? Is it being given to you in a form, by a user?

Comment: Correct. The user enters their info in the standard Wordpress registration form... which somehow triggers the action_hook that calls my function.

Comment: Without taking a closer look at your build, it's hard to say. You need to start going backwards down your stack to determine where that data is being lost, then try to make sure it gets to where you need it. What theme are you using?

Comment: It's a custom theme. I'm worried that the data isn't being lost, but rather not captured (yet). I know that the first_name property eventually gets defined, because I can see it if I check the user's profile. But I'm concerned the user_register hook might get triggered before the user is fully defined.

Answer (score 7):

The data you're looking for are already within the WP_USER object the function get_userdata() returns to you. To access user's first and last name just do as follow:

```
# Retrieve the user's data (here we suppose, of course, the user exists)
$new_user = get_userdata( $user_id );
# Get the user's first and last name
$first_name = $new_user->first_name;
$last_name = $new_user->last_name;
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/

Answer (score 2):

I think you're the same person who asked something [similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62063/no-first-name-or-user-firstname-property-in-wp-user-object) in the Wordpress StackExchange.

It's not an answer per se, but an explanation seems to be that there's a bug in the WP platform itself when obtaining these meta fields when called from mu-plugins code.

I've recently experienced this myself and I had some code in my functions.php that was called on the user_register hook. When that hook was defined in mu-plugins I got the issue you report. When that hook was defined in my functions.php it worked fine.