# Wordpress - New User Notification Email Include Name

Tags: php, wordpress

I've modified the New User Notification Email to include address details entered during the shopping cart of WooCommerce, but I also need to include the first and last name.

The following code will print the last name matching the hard coded ID...

```
$user_last = get_user_meta( 5952, 'last_name', true );
$message .= sprintf(__('Last Name: %s'), $user_last) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

Why does the following not print the last name matching the new users ID?

```
$user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', true );
$message .= sprintf(__('Last Name: %s'), $user_last) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

The following prints the correct ID that I'm trying to target, so this makes little sense to me...

```
$message .= sprintf(__('User ID: %s'), $user_id) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the user properties to get first and last name.

First Name: $user->first_name

Last Name: $user->last_name

If that doesn't work go in and check the user has a first and last name set.

Example:

```
printf( "Full Name: %s %s", $user->first_name, $user->last_name );
```

Or for your question replace:

```
$message .= sprintf(__('Last Name: %s'), $user_last) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

With:

```
$message .= sprintf(__('Last Name: %s'), $user->last_name) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: I tried the exact piece of code mentioned about and it printed 12.

I adjust to...
'code'$message .= sprintf( "Full Name: %s %s", $user->first_name, $user->last_name ) . "\r\n\r\n";'code'
This printed Full Name, but with no name.

I've already tried...
'code'$message .= sprintf(__('First Name: %s'), $user->first_name) . "\r\n\r\n";'code'
This didn't work either.

Hard coding the ID in printed...

User ID: 5942
Name: Kirk Johnston 

If I hard code the user ID as 5942 afterwards, it prints the name of the last person I signed up as.

Comment: I correct myself...
Hard coding the USER ID from a previous sign up, doesn't print out a name, which suggests no first name or last name is set, but if I go into the user from the admin, first and last names are completed.

Comment: No such luck and I've also tried...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995588/how-to-get-wordpress-users-first-name-from-wp-user-object

Comment: And this... http://wordpress.org/support/topic/first-last-name-to-new-user-email-notification

Comment: Thanks Nathan Dawson for trying to assist with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code...

```
$firstname = $_POST['billing_first_name'];
$lastname = $_POST['billing_last_name'];

$message .= sprintf(__('First Name: %s'), $firstname) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('Last Name: %s'), $lastname) . "\r\n\r\n";
```